# How to get the memory address(not the hashcode) of a java object using JVMTI

Tags: java, memory, object, jvmti

I am a beginner in C and C++ and I don't know very well how to use the JVMTI. I want to get the physical memory location (in hexadecimal) of a java object. Is it possible? I don't want to get answers like "get it from this profiler etc" ... 
So far I am using this command in linux terminal :

```
java -showversion -agentpath:../CPrg/DLL/bin/Debug/libDLL.so SimpleMemAlloc
```

The libDLL.so is the library I am creating using c where I run it with my java application. It actually works, it runs with my code but I don't know how to get the data I want.

For example I am using this simple code:

```
public class SimpleMemAlloc{

    Object [] oarray = new Object[10000];

    public static void main(String args []){
        Object [] o= new Object[100];
        for (int i= 0; i<100; i++){
        o[i] = new Integer [10000];
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get the memory location (0x...) of every new integer array that I create...
I will be very happy if I get a nice sample code using the jvmti

Comment: You realise that objects can be moved around in memory? (Although they can be temporarily pinned.)

Comment: Yes I know that ... Is there any way I can do this in JVMTI ... I don't care if the next second they move around ... I just want to find their actual memory location at that specific moment.

Comment: I believe you don't need it actually. Anyway `sun.misc.Unsafe` is what you search.

Comment: I've tried the Unsafe class but I couldn't find the memory location of an array... If I can with the Unsafe class I would be very happy if you show me how. But I believe jvmti is the answer... It might not make sense but I really need this, I am researching on something and this answer would be very helpfull for me

Answer (score 0):

If the object doesn't overwrite the `hashCode()` the default implementation returns the internal address of the object as a integer.  Again this might not be the best way of doing this.

> This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of
>   the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not
>   required by the JavaTM programming language.

For more info [click here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)

Comment: This is wrong. The identity hash code of an object is not an address. The identity hash code is constant, but the address can change. In particular, when the garbage collector copies the object to reclaim space.